# Xcode build ignores offline bundle, opens RN packager every time

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using RN 0.39 that I upgraded a while ago from an older version.

I want to build my application on my CI environment using xcodebuild.

First I run the RN-cli to get the offline bundle:

`react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle`

Then I'm simply run `xcodebuild` in the nimblest way possible:

`xcodebuild -scheme MyAppScheme -configuration Release`

No matter what schemes, targets or configurations, this always opens the RN Packager which I need to avoid in my CI environment.

The latest AppDelegate.m versions are supposed to pickup the offline bundle if it's present, I wonder why mine is not doing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: why not build it through xcode?

Comment: @AakashSigdel I'm setting up an automated builds through TeamCity, I want new builds with each commit. And if each build will open the RN Packager, then subsequent builds will fail on account of the packager using port 8081 from the previous build. Also the RN packager shouldn't be running in the first place when the offline bundle is present. I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: can't it be done with this command? `react-native run-ios --configuration Release --no-packager`

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe the latest AppDelegate.m files pick up the bundled file, as I was using 0.41 and it was loading the server all the time.

I have this, which will dynamically pick up the server or local file, depending if you are running debug or release builds. (Make sure you have a pre compiled flag of DEBUG=1 in your xCode):

```
#if DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

Comment: Interesting! I like this. That said, I'm not that proficient on XCode yet. How do I set those pre-compiled flags?

Comment: Look for the Build Settings - Apple LLVM 8.0 Preprocessing - Preprocessor Macros and in the Debug setting you should have something like DEBUG=1. I believe RN already does this for you but you should check.